# How to update my local master branch to include changes made to my local feature branch that are up-to-date on origin (remote) master?

Tags: git, github

TLDR: My local feature branch has merged with remote origin/master, but my local master is not merging with remote master ("already up to date") and git pull/fetch doesn't work.

The origin/master (remote) repo that I can see on github that my team is working on is up-to-date and working. It includes everything from both my master branch and feature branch.

My local master branch is missing data from the feature branch and is behind my team's remote origin/master.

My local feature branch is ahead of my local master branch but behind the origin/master.

How do I synchronize my local branches to be at the same level?

When I git pull/fetch on my local master it says it's up to date, but it's not.

Why did this happen? Should I have only merged my local feature with my local master branch, and then only merge my local master with remote origin/master?

Edit: It seems like my branches have only pulled from remote/origin master when I have pushed my changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you already merge your feature to master and don't have any missing changes on master, you can simple reset your master to origin. Go to master branch and try: `git reset --hard origin/master`.

I'm not sure why this happens, but already happened to me and I fix by this way.

Comment: I can't say this was helpful. It hard reset me to about a month ago, and then I have the same issue. I reset the reset (it says I'm up-to-date), and merged my feature branch into my local/master. Now my local master is only a few commits behind the remote master, but it still isn't getting any of the data from the remote origin/master.